# How do I perform groupby only the values that exist?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Platform     Genre      Score
PC           Action     9
PS           Adventure  8.5
Xbox         Action     9.5....
```

the dataframe is huge. I want to visualize a heatmap showing the platform on the x-axis, the Genre on y and the score as the value.

So i tried this:

```
abc=games.groupby(['platform','genre'])['score'].mean().reset_index()
abc=abc.pivot('platform','genre','score')
sns.heatmap(abc)
```

Now the problem is since not all the platform have games in all the genres, the resulting dataframe is having a lot of **NaN** values. If i use **abc.dropna()**, then all the rows are dropped.

So what should I do such that only the relevant values that are not NaN exist??

Comment: Show us an example

Comment: I you pivot in this way then the null values are inevitable. If you have the platform in the index and genre in the columns then you will have null values unless every genre-platform pair is in the data set. I don't know how `sns.heatmap` works but you could try filling the null values with `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [JoeCondron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3868428/joecondron) says, the pivot is giving it to you this way because it is creating a grid. However, I suspect you want it to be super clear in your heatmap that the values are null because if you create a platform X genre grid, those spots ARE going to exist -- just with that null value.

The sns.heatmap does that for you already but the values as defaulted give you a blue box which may be what you don't care for. Check out the [seaborn docs](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) and, at the bottom, it shows you how to mask out unwanted data.

In your case, this should provide you with "blank" boxes so long as your background is white. This works for me using Jupyter Notebook.

```
mask = abc.isnull()
with sns.axes_style("white"):
    sns.heatmap(abc, mask=mask)
plt.show()
```

With that said, it may be easier on the eyes if you had a softer grey type background and color. However, I think that achieves what you ultimately want.